# /shutdown: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-shared-245.so:

Tags: 20.04, shutdown

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 server that I get this error while shutting down. I'm not really sure why or what I can do to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

[Picture of log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r79si.jpg)

> /shutdown: error while loading shared libraries:
> libsystemd-shared-245.so: cannot open shared object file: so such file
> or directory

Here is output from ldd /usr/bin/systemd-machine-id-setup the file is most definitely there.

```
ldd /usr/bin/systemd-machine-id-setup
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc9bdc3000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe27b937000)
libsystemd-shared-245.so => /lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-245.so (0x00007fe27b6de000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe27bb77000)
libacl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1 (0x00007fe27b6d3000)
libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007fe27b67c000)
libcap.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2 (0x00007fe27b673000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fe27b638000)
libcryptsetup.so.12 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcryptsetup.so.12 (0x00007fe27b5c6000)
libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007fe27b4a8000)
libidn2.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007fe27b487000)
libip4tc.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libip4tc.so.2 (0x00007fe27b47d000)
libkmod.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmod.so.2 (0x00007fe27b462000)
liblz4.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007fe27b441000)
libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007fe27b3fb000)
libpam.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0 (0x00007fe27b3e9000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fe27b3e4000)
libseccomp.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libseccomp.so.2 (0x00007fe27b3c2000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fe27b396000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fe27b36d000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe27b366000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fe27b35d000)
libdevmapper.so.1.02.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdevmapper.so.1.02.1 (0x00007fe27b2f2000)
libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007fe27b01c000)
libargon2.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libargon2.so.1 (0x00007fe27b012000)
libjson-c.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-c.so.4 (0x00007fe27affe000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007fe27afdb000)
libunistring.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007fe27ae59000)
libaudit.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1 (0x00007fe27ae2d000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe27ae28000)
libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007fe27ad96000)
libudev.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x00007fe27ad69000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe27ac85000)
libcap-ng.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap-ng.so.0 (0x00007fe27ac7d000)
```

Comment: What is `/shutdown`? Please add output of `find / -name libsystemd-shared-245.so` and `ldd /lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-245.so`  to the question. If long - use pastebin.